# Running video on html from specific point

Tags: javascript, video.js

I am trying to play a video from specific point , but it is giving error as "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null" .

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> 
 <html> 
<body> 

    <video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176" controls>
        <source src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.webm" type="video/webm">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>

    <script>
        var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
        vid.onloadedmetadata = function () {

            document.getElementById('vid').addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function () {
                this.currentTime = 50;
            }, false);

        };
    </script> 

    <p>Video courtesy of <a href="https://www.bigbuckbunny.org/" target="_blank">Big Buck Bunny</a>.</p>

</body>
```

Comment: `vid.addEventListener` Also, you're already overwriting `onloadedmetadata`, so you don't need to add an event listener for the same event. Just state the function directly.

Comment: Where is the element with `id="vid"`? You probably meant `vid.addEventListener`

Comment: thanks chris , i corrected that , but it is not playing from 50 .

Comment: You want this, basically: `vid.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function () { this.currentTime = 50; this.play(); }, false);`

Comment: Yes , but this is also not working , it is not playing from 50

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('vid')` uses the id `vid` but your video has id `myVideo`.

This was hinted by "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' **of null**"

You also seem to want to add an eventHandler twice... Here's the corrected code, I think.

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.onloadedmetadata = function () {
    this.currentTime = 50;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks .. i got this working using

```
  <script>
        var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
        vid.onloadedmetadata = function () {
            this.currentTime = 10;
            this.play();

        };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the length of the video is less then 50s, setting currentTime to a number of seconds less than or equal to the length of the video will work :

```html
<body> 

  <video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176" controls>
    <source src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.webm" type="video/webm">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>

  <script>
    var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
      vid.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function () {
        this.currentTime = 30; // play from 30th second
        this.volume = .1; // Just to not play loudly and scare everyone around
        this.play();
      }, false);
  </script> 

  <p>Video courtesy of <a href="https://www.bigbuckbunny.org/" target="_blank">Big Buck Bunny</a>.</p>

</body>
```